# Is there a wall level that archers can't shoot over?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Will archers be able to shoot over a wall regardless of it's level, or are archers unable to shoot over a wall after it's a certain level?

Comment: Upgrading walls only improve its hitpoints, no other functions included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Walls' only effect is to stop ground troops, with the exception of hog riders, that are not under the influence of a jump spell, from passing through them. Any troop that have a long enough range are able to hit buildings on the other side of the wall. The level of the wall will only influence how much hit points the wall have and does not provide any special effects.

Answer (score -1):

im pretty sure that a archer could shoot over any lvl walls as long as they are close enough

Comment: Can you please cite a source and be more specific?